# Using Mongoid to do counts of embedded objects

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I have 2 collections, Article, Author.   An article can have 0 to N number of Authors.  An article can be one of many article_types ( article_type is a String ).

Article
 ...
 field :article_type :type => String
 ...
 has and belongs to many :authors
 ...

Author
 field :author_name :type => String
 ....

What is the best way to use Mongoid to get the number of articles that each author belongs to for a specific article type.   For example, the output should be a hash:

'John Smith' : 2 
'Mary Jones' : 10
'Tom Petty'  : 22

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use map reduce http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#map_reduce

Comment: Already using that but it is WAY slow.  Any other ideas?  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The Aggregation Framework is recommended as it can be 5-10 times faster than map/reduce.  The MongoDB documention is at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/ but to access it from Mongoid, you have to dip down to the Moped level using Article.collection.aggregate or Author.collection.aggregate.  Reference [Aggregate with Mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205650/aggregate-with-mongoid)